# What is the most efficient way to get a table or attribute table of a float raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, zonal-statistics

I'm starting with a stretch point raster.  Ultimately I want to get a mean value of values with larger zones and then rate the zonal mean stretching from 0-1 and output rank/zone to a table or layer with an attribute table.

After using zonal statistics to get the mean per zone.  I've been using the geomorphometry and gradient metrics>Transformations>Normalize Tool to rank which results in a 0-1 floating point raster with decimals (still no attribute table).  I realize I could convert this raster to a integer and then finally to polygon or table but there must be a more efficient way to do all of this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go all the way to polygon.  When you convert to integer you should get a raster attribute table with a count for the number of cells in each row.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I ran across seeing the attribute table on the integer raster.  Now I just have to figure out how to rank these values...

Comment: Data Management - General - Sort should do the trick. I'm not sure if it needs to be vector or if you can sort a raster attribute table. My guess is the former.